# How to call a native interface function for IOS in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I read the  following guides for native interface.

```
https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html
```

and

`https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_native_interfaces`

I do the Hello World test and can't find the call for IOS to the native interface in the codename one file.
I did the .h and the .m and the "generate native access". After this, I cannot check out to go on. 
My intension is to call a "copy from clipboard" and "paste from clipboard" native from IOS.

How do I call the native interface function hello world in codename one for IOS?

What should I import?

Is there anywhere a complete sample for IOS and native interface?

These are the files what I have now from the tutorial.

OK, the content of h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface com_mycompany_crtome_native_callsImpl : NSObject {
}

-(NSString*)helloWorld:(NSString*)param;
-(BOOL)isSupported;
@end
```

Then the m file:

```
#import "com_mycompany_crtome_native_callsImpl.h"

@implementation com_mycompany_crtome_native_callsImpl

-(NSString*)helloWorld:(NSString*)param{
    NSLog(@"MyApp: %@", param);
    return @"Tada";
}

-(BOOL)isSupported{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Then I have an extra java file called native_calls.java:

```
package com.mycompany.crtome;

import com.codename1.system.NativeInterface;

public interface native_calls extends NativeInterface {
    String helloWorld(String hi);
}
```

So, I don't know how do I call that from my main java file?

And may you explain the function and the calls step by step?

Comment: Generate native access creates the h and m files. It's unclear where you are stuck. What's the content of your native interface? What is the problem in the native side, you normally only need to edit the m file.

Comment: I added additional information, and thanks a lot for your help.
It would be nice, when I could understand, what's going on, while I call a native interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that binds the native interface to the iOS code is generated automatically. To use the native interface just use:

```
native_call n = NativeLookup.lookup(native_call.class);
if(n != null && n.isSupported()) {
   String result = n.helloWorld("Hi There");
}
```

Comment: Do I have something to import in the main file or is it automatically binded by generating?

Comment: It's not working. lookup is not implemented in this case.

`native_calls n = NativeLookup.lookup(native_calls.class);
        if(n != null && n.isSupported()) {
           String result = n.helloWorld("Hi There");
        }`

compiler says "cannot find symbol method lookup"

Comment: if I try it with `Native_calls n = NativeLookup.create(native_calls.class);`

compiler says:

error: class native_calls is public, should be declared in a file named native_calls.java
public class native_calls implements com.mycompany.crtome.cative_calls{.....

I don't know how to go on.

Comment: In Java all classes must be in a java file that corresponds to the class name and is case sensitive. You bucked the trend in Java by using lower case for the name of the class you might have made that mistake with the native interface. It needs to be within a file named exactly `native_calls.java`.

Comment: OK, I change this, no compiler error. 
The problem is `n.isSupported()` it is not true, so the n.helloWorld... will not start. And there is no NativeLookup.lookup.

Comment: It works with `NativeLookup.create`, when I compile it on the codename server and test it on the hardware. Thanks a lot.